# How to get the source code of site "developer.android.com"?

Tags: android, documentation-generation

In fact, I've found the source files of site "source.android.com" at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/docs/source.android.com  It uses markdown format to write articles and use related python tools to generate the web site.

Although the static html file of the developer site can be downloaded through sdk tools, but I want to get the source code similar to which I get from site source.android.com, not just the static html content. In my opinion, the site must be generated by some useful tools, for example javadoc. Is that true?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried git cloning the repo to your computer and following the directions in README? It seems like you just run a python script and it generates the HTML from the markdown.

Comment: the site must be generated by some useful tools, for example javadoc? Can you explain what do you mean there?

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa Yes，I can get "How to Build source.android.com" from README. But my objective is to get "How to Build developer.android.com" if there exists similar repo of the developer site.

Comment: @Anshu I've found the repo that generate "source.android.com", it use markdown and python tools. I think there must be similar tools to generate developer.android.com, at lease the api reference at the site is generate by javadoc? so how about the link to api reference in articles of dev guide? I guess there also some tool but I don't know which tool can help me do it.

Comment: Ah, I misread the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean building developer documentation which is located on [Android SDK]/docs?
All you need to do is 'make sdk'. This will make the android sdk from full source, including developer documentation.

Steps to make developer documentation :

1. Download android source from [source.android.com](http://source.android.com)
2. Set build environment with following command :

   $ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master -g all,-notdefault,tools

   if you already downloaded the source, just type

   $ repo init -g all ; repo sync
3. invoke following command to build Android SDK

   $ cd [ANDROID_FULL_SOURCE_DIR]
   $ . build/envsetup.sh (or source build/envsetup.sh on mac)
   $ lunch sdk-eng
   $ make sdk
4. The documentation will be generated at out/host/[HOST_OS]-[HOST_ARCH]/sdk/ folder.